# How to install ConTeXt from CD-ROM?

Tags: installing, context, context-mkiv

I would like to prepare a current version of ConTeXt on a CD-ROM, so that it can be installed on Debian, in some emergency situation, i.e. when Internet access is unavailable. The typical installation method I have seen is through the Internet only. Debian provides packages, but these are very outdated. Is there a way to download the entire ConTeXt repository to a CD-ROM for later installation?

Comment: Is there something wrong with using a TeX Live CD?

Comment: As I know, TeX Live no longer comes on CDs, but only on DVDs. Also, the version of ConTeXt included with TeX Live is older, and might not work with my files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the script `first-setup.sh` does a `rsync` to get the latest ConTeXt version:

```
rsync -rlptv rsync://contextgarden.net/minimals/setup/$platform/bin .
```

you can write a new version to your DVD and then modify the install script to use the DVD as repository, eg:

```
rsync -rlptv rsync:///cdrom/minimals/setup/$platform/bin .
```